# Mapping between HDFS Daemon and Kerberos Principal and Unix Account

Tags: unix, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos, account

In my organization, to access the hadoop cluster we do the following on the Gateway:

```
sudo su -

cd /etc/username/

kinit some_string/instance -k -t some_string.keytab

hadoop fs -ls
```

This works perfectly fine, but I am trying to understand what exactly is going on.

When I do a 'whoami' obviously it shows 'root'. But any files created the above way on HDFS have the owner as 'some_string' and group as 'hdfs'. And I can neither kinit nor access HDFS as any other user. Why is this so?

Is this because: Hadoop's HDFS daemon is mapped to the kerberos principal (and that principal's ticket is only accessible to me as a root user?) And that principal is also mapped to the OS account some_string which is what i see as owner of the files on HDFS? If so where is the link defined (hadoop daemon to principal to os account)

I tried googling around a lot but could not find a definitive answer to my confusion. Even when I log in to HUE with my own user, I do not have write access to these files, which is also something I want to understand how to resolve.

Thanks.

Edit:

```
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal:     some_string/instance@CLOUDERA.xxxx.CORP

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
03/02/16 21:06:19  03/03/16 21:06:19      krbtgt/CLOUDERA.xxxx.CORP@CLOUDERA.xxxx.CORP
renew until 03/02/16 21:06:19
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you are executing below command

```
kinit some_string/instance -k -t some_string.keytab
```

You are requesting for ticket of the principal which is stored in your *some_string.keytab* file which you can look at by using below command

```
klist -k some_string.keytab
```

It will show you output with principal name and version. Keytab files contains password as well so it dose not ask for password.

And the second question will be answer from the *klist* command it will show you the principal which is like user/_host@realm so in your case user is some_string, and when you get ticket of some_string user you are some_string for kerberos and your commands will be executed as some_string user so the owner of files created will be some_string.

Also you can list the tickets which you already have using *klist* command see below the output:

```
[root@myhostname ~]# klist -k some_Name.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:some_Name.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 myuser/myhostname@MYREAL.COM
```

Here my keytab is of myuser user and host is myhostname host.

Comment: I added klist to the question, you said '...in your case user is hdfs...', but looks like it is not. In the principal, the user is 'some_string'.

Comment: @Gadam let me know the output of klist -k some_string.keytab

Comment: sorry for the delay in response. here it is: 17:20:20 $ klist -k some_string.keytab
Keytab name: FILE:some_string.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2 some_string/devgtway01.northamerica.xxxxx.net@CLOUDERA.xxxxx.CORP  (This last line is repeated 6 times)

Comment: @Gadam that's right i missed that you said your files are created with owner as some_string so when you get ticket for some_string you are no longer root for kerberos you are not some_string user for him and file permission are proof of that for you. So in same way you can get ticket of any other user and there it will behave the same.